# How to build style and script into one single file in shopify extension?

Tags: shopify, vite

I am currently working with Shopify post-purchase extension. Now google chrome's post-purchase extension asks for only JavaScript. But, my own custom styling building on main.css file. Since my browser is not getting style file, style can not be applied on the components.
So, I want to achieve either getting the style file or building everything into main.js.

Comment: You just use Shopify checkout styles in your extension. There is no way they are going to let you inject random CSS into their nice checkout and have it turn that checkout experience into something weird. At least that is how I think of it. You write JS, and add functionality, you're not painting a Picasso.